# Get Gradle sync failed: java.lang.NullPointerException when import android project from git

Tags: android-studio, gradle, github

I download new android studio 3.5.1.
When I create new project it is okay to work.
But, when I pulled a android project from git (it working ok before) and import it get this error "Gradle sync failed: java.lang.NullPointerException". And no more information.
How can I fix this error?

I had rebuild,Sync project with gradle file, invalidate cache/restart but it not work

Comment: Please give more Details your Question..? your error hase occurred : Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

Comment: I had reslove it, because when installing missing lib

Comment: Now let me know if there is any error